# Update object's text in Solar2D (ex-CoronaSDK)

Tags: text, lua, coronasdk

I want to display a text with a number and to update the number when pressing a button. Here is what I got right now:

```
local oxyPar = 10
--the oxyPar is just a number

local oxyOpt =
{
   text = "Oxygen: ".. tostring( oxyPar )
   --all other text parameters
  }

local oxygen = display.newText( oxyOpt )
--display a text calling oxyOpt table for the parameters

local timeOpt =
{
   --all the button parameters
   onRelease = timeOn
   --call timeOn function on the button release
}

local timeBtn = widget.newButton( timeOpt )
--a button that calls timeOpt table for the parameters

local function timeOn( listener )
   oxyPar = oxyPar + 1
end
```

After pressing the button the oxyPar (the number) should grow by one, but the text still shows up **Oxygen: 10** instead of **Oxygen: 11**. Is there a way to update the text so it shows the new number?

Comment: `timeOn` is used before been defined

Comment: Thank you very much! I did it and got an error, but it was because I did the same with the texts so I fixed the order of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing `oxyPar` does not affect your display object `oxygen`.

A number value is copied by value so

```
local oxyPar = 10
local oxyOpt = {text = tostring(oxyPar)}
local oxygen = display.newText( oxyOpt )
```

is equivalent to

```
local oxyOpt = {text = "10"}
local oxygen = display.newText( oxyOpt )
```

There is no relation between `oxyPar` and `oxyOpt` as you simply copied the return value of `tostring(10)` into `oxyOpt.text` which is a different variable.

Change `ogygen.text` instead

Please refer to the Solar2d reference manual.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newText.html

> Updating Text Post-Creation
>
> ```
> local myText = display.newText( "hello", 100, 200, native.systemFont, 12 )
> myText:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0.5 )
>  
> -- Change the displayed text
> myText.text = "Hello World!"
> ```

Comment: Yes, that's also what I tried but the main problem was actually what egor skriptunoff pointed out in his comment.